# Sqllite: finding abnormal values over time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following sqllite table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    date TEXT, 
    account TEXT, 
    ........
    value TEXT, 
    .......
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT composite UNIQUE (date, account)
    )
```

I want to find all the account numbers where the value is greater than 0 on 2 separate dates . I'm thinking:

```
SELECT * from test WHERE value> 0 GROUP BY account
```

is probably a start, but I don't know how to evaluate the size of groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to phrase this query is to aggregate over accounts having a greater than zero value, and then retain those accounts having two or more distinct dates:

```
SELECT
    account
FROM test
WHERE value > 0
GROUP BY account
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date) >= 2
```

I see that your `value` column is declared as `TEXT`.  I think this should probably be an integer if you want to do numeric comparisons with this column.

Comment: Thanks, as a quick follow up question: I notice that only one row per date is visible in the output. Is there a way to see all the rows with the same account number but different date, so that I can see values over time?

Comment: You should ask a new question as this is a big departure from your original question.