# Sqlite: tracking values over time

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image]

This is a follow up to [Sqllite: finding abnormal values over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486103/sqllite-finding-abnormal-values-over-time/45486179?noredirect=1#comment78023861_45486179)

Once again I have the following sqllite table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    date TEXT, 
    account TEXT, 
    ........
    value INTEGER, 
    .......
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT composite UNIQUE (date, account)
    )
```

I want to find all the rows where the value is greater than 0 on 2 separate dates . I'm thinking:

```
SELECT * from test WHERE value> 0 GROUP BY account
```

is probably a start. The answer from the last question does yield the account number, but I would like see all the rows for each account number on their different dates, in order to track values over time.

BTW, in the screenshot the headers are ID, DATE, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, VALUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE account IN (
    SELECT a.acount
    FROM test a
    JOIN test b
    ON a.account = b.account 
       AND a.date <> b.date
       AND a.value > 0 
       AND b.value > 0
)
ORDER BY account, date
```

Comment: Thank you , that does work. What if I had 3 separate dates?